# Is there a specific term for a collateral with a value less than what has been declared?

Tags: banking, collateral

In other words, a collateral value has been estimated more than its real value. Is there a term for this type of collateral? Is the term "over-declared collateral" correct in this sense?

Comment: was this over-declaration at the start of the loan, or was it because it lost value during the period of the loan?

Comment: At the start of the loan.

Comment: Was it _knowingly_ over-declared or a genuine error in estimation?